# Vagrant unable to connect to docker through ssh

Tags: ssh, docker, vagrant, centos7, openssh

I'm trying to connect to docker instance through vagrant.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
#RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install openssh-server wget sudo
EXPOSE 22
RUN mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.ssh
RUN chmod 0700 /home/vagrant/.ssh
RUN useradd --create-home -s /bin/bash vagrant
WORKDIR /home/vagrant
RUN mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.ssh
RUN echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22WDkTkyrtvp9eWW6A8YVr+kz4TjGYe7gHzIw+niNltGEFHzD8+v1I2YJ6oXevct1YeS0o9HZyN1Q9qgCgzUFtdOKLv6IedplqoPkcmF0aYet2PkEDo3MlTBckFXPITAMzF8dJSIFo9D8HfdOV0IAdx4O7PtixWKn5y2hMNG0zQPyUecp4pzC6kivAIhyfHilFR61RGL+GPXQ2MWZWFYbAGjyiYJnAmCP3NOTd0jMZEnDkbUvxhMmBYSdETk1rRgm+R4LOzFUGaHqHDLKLX+FIPKcF96hrucXzcWyLbIbEgE98OHlnVYCzRdK8jlqm8tehUc9c9WhQ== vagrant insecure public key" > /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chmod 0600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown -R vagrant: /home/vagrant/.ssh
RUN mkdir -p /etc/sudoers.d
RUN install -b -m 0440 /dev/null /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
RUN echo 'vagrant ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
RUN sed -i 's|#AuthorizedKeysFile|AuthorizedKeysFile|g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

And here is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.build_dir = "."
    d.name = "test"
    d.has_ssh = true
  end
  config.ssh.port = 22
end
```

And after **vagrant up** I get this:

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 172.17.0.2:22
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
```

And it's printing last row many times, unlit I stop it with Ctrl-C.

If I just **run docker build -t stacko . && docker run stacko** process will stuck here:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

What could be wrong?

**My Solution**

It seems to be that problem was with docker host keys. So I regenerated them

```
FROM centos:7

ENV container docker

# Stuck at “loaded plugins: fastestmirror” fix
RUN rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__*
RUN rpm --rebuilddb -v -v

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install openssh-server openssh-clients sudo
RUN yum clean all

RUN rm -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
RUN rm -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
RUN rm -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
RUN ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
RUN ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
RUN ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

RUN useradd -s /bin/bash vagrant
RUN echo -n 'vagrant:vagrant' | chpasswd
RUN mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.ssh
RUN chmod 0700 /home/vagrant/.ssh
RUN echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22WDkTkyrtvp9eWW6A8YVr+kz4TjGYe7gHzIw+niNltGEFHzD8+v1I2YJ6oXevct1YeS0o9HZyN1Q9qgCgzUFtdOKLv6IedplqoPkcmF0aYet2PkEDo3MlTBckFXPITAMzF8dJSIFo9D8HfdOV0IAdx4O7PtixWKn5y2hMNG0zQPyUecp4pzC6kivAIhyfHilFR61RGL+GPXQ2MWZWFYbAGjyiYJnAmCP3NOTd0jMZEnDkbUvxhMmBYSdETk1rRgm+R4LOzFUGaHqHDLKLX+FIPKcF96hrucXzcWyLbIbEgE98OHlnVYCzRdK8jlqm8tehUc9c9WhQ== vagrant insecure public key" > /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chmod 0600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown -R vagrant: /home/vagrant/.ssh
RUN mkdir -p /etc/sudoers.d
RUN install -b -m 0440 /dev/null /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
RUN echo 'vagrant ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
RUN sed -i 's/Defaults    requiretty/#Defaults    requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

It would be cool, if solmeone could explain me why is this working (what's wrong was with ssh keys)

Comment: Your ssh is not running at all, that's why. You need to better understand docker CMD: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: @michael_bitard. You mean that only last CMD is executed? But how then I can leave container in running state?

Comment: You can't, when you `docker build`, every process is stopped between two lines of your Dockerfile, you have to start your ssh server when you use `docker run`

Comment: @michael_bitard. You mean like that: **sudo vagrant docker-run -- service ssh restart** ? But that does not work. Gives error: **Stderr: /usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: Container command 'service' not found or does not exist.**

Comment: @michael_bitard. I edited my Dockerfiel. I suppose now ssh should be running? But now I'm getting **default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...**

Comment: What happen if you `docker run -p22:22 yourimage` then try to `ssh vagrant@yourip` ?

Comment: In your non-working Dockerfile, what is giving you `ls -al /etc/ssh/ssh*key` ?